# How to use another classes member variables in c++?

Tags: c++, class

I'm currently programming a Yahtzee game, and I'm having trouble with some of my classes

I have two classes, Player, and Scorecard.

```
class Player {
  private:
    string name;
    Scorecard scorecard;
};


class Scorecard {
  public:
    void display() {
      //...
    }
};
```

(All the classes have the appropriate getters and setters)

I'd like the scorecard class to be able to display the name of the player to the user. Is there any way that can be done?

Comment: This makes my cringe `All the classes have the appropriate getters and setters`. Properly designed class don't need getters/setters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not have Scorecard print the Player's name.  A player *has-a* scorecard.  A scorecard does not have a a player.

The Player class should have a `display` method that displays the player's name followed by the score card:

```
class Player
{
  private:
     string name;
     Scorecard scorecard;

  public:
    void display(void)
    {
        cout << "Player name: " << name << endl;
        scorecard.display();
    }
};
```

Also, since Player contains a Scorecard, you should declare the Scorecard class before class Player:

```
class Scorecard
{
 /*... */
};

class Player
{
 /* ... */
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to somehow give Scorecard the instance of player. Also, Player needs either a public getter or make `name` public.

Comment: Sorry, Player has getters and setters for all it's variables. I've added that in

Comment: You really ought to spell out the names you gave the getters and setters.  They're not standardized in C++ like they are in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is to add a public accessor method to Player that returns either a copy or constant reference to Player::name.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem that Scorecard has no reference to Player.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options.

1. Pass name as a parameter to `display()` function. (You are calling `display()` from within a member function of `Player`, right? If not, you'll also need to add a public accessor method to `Player` for getting its name.)
2. Pass a reference to the owining `Player` to `Scorecard` object (e.g. via constructor) and store it within `Scorecard`. Add a public accessor menthod to `Player` for getting its name.

Personally, I like (1) better, because it allows to minimize dependencies between `Player` and `Scorecard` classes.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a PlayerName property to the Scorecard, and then it will be able to store a name.
then the display() function will get the name as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

Typically, I'd tell the `Scorecard` about the `Player` that owns it:

```
class Scorecard;

class Player {
  public:
    explicit Player(const string& name_): name(name_), scorecard(*this) {}
    const string& Name(oid) const { return name; }
  private:
    string name;
    Scorecard scorecard;
};

class Scorecard {
  public:
    Scorecard(Player& player_): player(player_) {}
    void display() {
      cout << player.Name() << endl;
      //...
    }
  private:
    Player& player;
};
```